# How to check whether a connection is alive while we choose keep-alive connection?

Tags: sockets, unix

When we choose keep-alive connection to communicate with server, we always face the problem that server may close the connection occasionally. Then, we get an error while using this connection. Instead of trying again, do we have another choice to avoid this kind of problem? Is there a proper way to check whether a connection is alive before we use it?

Any suggestion is welcome, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using HTTP keep-alive the client always has to be aware that another  request on the connection might conflict with a connection close from the server.

Even if you would be able to be sure that the connection is alive at the client at the very moment when you send the HTTP request there is still a race. Since it takes some time for the TCP data from the client to arrive at the server and some time for a close (TCP FIN) from the server to arrive at the client, there is a chance that the server has already closed the connection but the client does not now, or that the server closes the connection before it reads the new data from the client.

Comment: Is it helpful to try to read from the connection each time before the client send data to server?

Comment: @scott: While this will reduce the race since you will detect if the server just recently has closed the connection. But it will not eliminate the race since you will not detect if the FIN is just in transit or if it is sent before the server reads your request. Thus it is helpful to reduce the cases where you need to retry but will not solve your problem completely.